# MySQL ERROR 1005: Can't create table

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-error-1005

I am trying to create a table but I keep getting Error 1005. ): Please help!

```
Executing SQL script in server
ERROR: Error 1005: Can't create table 'czhen_hockey_db.hockey_db' (errno: 150)
SQL Code:
        -- -----------------------------------------------------
        -- Table `czhen_hockey_db`.`hockey_db`
        -- -----------------------------------------------------
        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `czhen_hockey_db`.`hockey_db` (
      `id` INT NOT NULL,
      `Date` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
      `Time` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
      `rink_id` INT NOT NULL,
      `division/team_id` INT NOT NULL,
      `opponent_id` INT NOT NULL,
      INDEX `fk_hockey_db_rink_idx` (`rink_id` ASC),
      INDEX `fk_hockey_db_division/team1_idx` (`division/team_id` ASC),
      INDEX `fk_hockey_db_opponent1_idx` (`opponent_id` ASC),
      PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
      CONSTRAINT `fk_hockey_db_rink`
        FOREIGN KEY (`rink_id`)
        REFERENCES `czhen_hockey_db`.`rink` (`rink_id`)
        ON DELETE NO ACTION
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
      CONSTRAINT `fk_hockey_db_division/team1`
        FOREIGN KEY (`division/team_id`)
        REFERENCES `czhen_hockey_db`.`division/team` (`division/team_id`)
        ON DELETE NO ACTION
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
      CONSTRAINT `fk_hockey_db_opponent1`
        FOREIGN KEY (`opponent_id`)
        REFERENCES `czhen_hockey_db`.`opponent` (`opponent_name`)
        ON DELETE NO ACTION
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
    ENGINE = InnoDB
```

SQL script execution finished: statements: 8 succeeded, 1 failed

Answer (score 0):

SQL 1005 is related to Foreign key problem. So please check whether "RINK", "OPPONENT" and "division/team" tables exist with specified primary keys.

I think for Opponent table you have to specify opponent_id as foreign key in place of opponent_name.

Please check

Answer (score -1):

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `czhen_hockey_db`.`hockey_db` (
      `id` INT NOT NULL,
      `Date` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
      `Time` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
      `rink_id` INT NOT NULL,
      `division/team_id` INT NOT NULL,
      `opponent_id` INT NOT NULL,
      INDEX `fk_hockey_db_rink_idx` (`rink_id` ASC),
      INDEX `fk_hockey_db_division/team1_idx` (`division/team_id` ASC),
      INDEX `fk_hockey_db_opponent1_idx` (`opponent_id` ASC),
      PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
      CONSTRAINT `fk_hockey_db_rink`
        FOREIGN KEY (`rink_id`)
        REFERENCES `czhen_hockey_db`.`rink` (`rink_id`)
        ON DELETE NO ACTION
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
      CONSTRAINT `fk_hockey_db_division/team1`
        FOREIGN KEY (`division/team_id`)
        REFERENCES `czhen_hockey_db`.`division/team` (`division/team_id`)
        ON DELETE NO ACTION
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
      CONSTRAINT `fk_hockey_db_opponent1`
        FOREIGN KEY (`opponent_id`)
        REFERENCES `czhen_hockey_db`.`opponent` (`opponent_name`)
        ON DELETE NO ACTION
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
    ENGINE = InnoDB
```